# Merge every two elements into 1 element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Suppose I have the following array in JavaScript:

```
var dataArray= [
    'name1\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name2\n' +
    'name3',
     ' \n' +
    'name4\n' +
    'name5\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name6\n' +
    'name7\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name8',
      'name9\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name10\n' +
    'name11',
  ' \n' +
    'name12\n' +
    'name13\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name14\n' +
    'name15',
'name16\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name17\n' +
    'name18',
 ' \n' +
    'name19\n' +
    'name20\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name21\n' +
    'name22\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name23',
  'name24\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name25\n' +
    'name26',
  ' \n' +
    'name27\n' +
    'name28\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name29\n' +
    'name30',
]
```

How can I write code to merge every two elements into one element? So that each pair, is only separated by 1 comma?

I'm looking to get the following output:

```
var dataArray= [
    'name1\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name2\n' +
    'name3'
     ' \n' +
    'name4\n' +
    'name5\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name6\n' +
    'name7\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name8',
      'name9\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name10\n' +
    'name11'
  ' \n' +
    'name12\n' +
    'name13\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name14\n' +
    'name15',
'name16\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name17\n' +
    'name18'
 ' \n' +
    'name19\n' +
    'name20\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name21\n' +
    'name22\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name23',
  'name24\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name25\n' +
    'name26',
  ' \n' +
    'name27\n' +
    'name28\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name29\n' +
    'name30',
]
```

I want it to be like the above, whereby every 2 elements are amalgamated.

Comment: Please show some code where you've attempted to solve the problem. Also, see: [Ask].

Comment: Why are you using arrays at all?  You just have one giant string in the array.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's hard to see, but there are commas.

Comment: @hev1 -  Well, the fact that it's that hard to see shows how poorly formatted it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.from`, assuming that the length of the array is even.

```
const res = Array.from({length:dataArray.length/2}, (_,i)=>dataArray[2*i]+dataArray[2*i+1]);
```

```js
var dataArray= [
    'name1\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name2\n' +
    'name3',
     ' \n' +
    'name4\n' +
    'name5\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name6\n' +
    'name7\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name8',
      'name9\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name10\n' +
    'name11',
  ' \n' +
    'name12\n' +
    'name13\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name14\n' +
    'name15',
'name16\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name17\n' +
    'name18',
 ' \n' +
    'name19\n' +
    'name20\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name21\n' +
    'name22\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name23',
  'name24\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name25\n' +
    'name26',
  ' \n' +
    'name27\n' +
    'name28\n' +
    '\n' +
    'name29\n' +
    'name30',
];
const res = Array.from({length:dataArray.length/2}, (_,i)=>dataArray[2*i]+dataArray[2*i+1]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Lucaso Glad to help.